# How to map my class to get the db's records with a custom method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm developing a website with ASP.NET MVC, NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate and want to know how can I customize my Map to get records using a custom Method.

My entities:

```
public class ImageGallery {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Titulo { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
public class Image {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ImageGallery ImageGallery { get; set; }
    public virtual string Low { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

My Fluent NHibernate Maps:

```
public class ImageGalleryMap:ClassMap<ImageGallery> {
    public ImageGalleryMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Titulo);
        HasMany(x => x.Images)
            .KeyColumn("ImageGalleryID");
        Map(x => x.IsActive);
    }
}
public class ImageMap:ClassMap<Image> {
    public ImageMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.ImageGallery);
        Map(x => x.Low);
        Map(x => x.IsActive);
    }
}
```

And, a method on my ImageRepository class:

```
    public IList<Image> ListActive() {
        return this.Session.CreateCriteria<Image>()
                           .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsActive", true))
                   .List<Image>();
    }
```

If I create an object this way:

```
ImageGallery ig = new ImageGallery();
```

I can access my the Image's list using:

```
foreach(Image img in ig.Images) {
   ...
}
```

However, ig.Images give me access to all images records and I would like to access just active records (or another criteria), using ListActive()'s repository methods.

How can I specify this on my Map?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Where constraint in the mapping will limit the Images to active ones always:

```
public class ImageMap:ClassMap<Image> {
    public ImageMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.ImageGallery);
        Map(x => x.Low);
        Map(x => x.IsActive);
        Where("IsActive = 1");
    }
}
```

If you want to load the Images collection but dynamically filter it for active records, the best way is to create an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Image> Active(this IEnumerable<Image> images)
{
    return images.Where(x => x.IsActive);
}
```

Then you can access the active records like this:

```
foreach(Image img in ig.Images.Active()) {
   ...
}
```

I like the extension method solution because it can be used on any `IEnumerable<Image>`, not just the collection on ImageGallery. I would definitely use this solution unless loading inactive images was a measurable performance problem.

If you want to selectively load active Images only then start by [reading this article about NHibernate Filters](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/05/04/nhibernate-filters.aspx) because I don't have any experience with them.